# Gravity in accelerometric measurements

Tags: matlab, filter, accelerometer

I have taken from a data set the values ​​of x and z of activity (e.g. walking, running) detected by an accelerometer. Since the data collected also contains the gravity values, I removed it with the following filter in Matlab:

```
fc = 0.3;
fs = 50;
x = ...;
y = ...;
z = ...;

[but,att] = butter(6,fc/(fs/2));

gx = filter(but,att,x);
gy = filter(but,att,y);
gz = filter(but,att,z);

new_x = x-gx;
new_y = y-gy;
new_z = z-gz;

A = magnitude(new_x,new_y,new_z);

plot(A)
```

Then I calculated the magnitude value and plotted the magnitude value on a graph.

However, every graph, even after removing gravity, starts with a magnitude of 1g (9.8 m / s ^ 2), why? Should not it start at 0 since I removed gravity?

Comment: You are probably seeing the transient of the filter. The filter takes time to converge. Try plotting `gx`

Comment: But gx in this case is the component of gravity on the x axis and it's the component that I want to remove from the accelerometer data, so I do not want to plot it

Comment: My point is, plot it (or observe the values) to see how it starts at 0 and then gradually increases. It's normal for a filter not to give the desired result at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the filter value to ramp up.  Include some additional data that you don't graph at the beginning of the file for this purpose.

How accurate do your calculations need to be?  With walking and running the angle of the accelerometer can change, so the orientation of the gravity vector can change throughout the gait cycle. How much of a change in orientation you can expect to see depends on the sensor location and the particular motion you are trying to capture.